# isn't the angularjs ui-router resolve insecure?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, meteor

If i have the current state

```
.state("display",
    {url:"/display",templateUrl:"display.ng.html",
    controller:"DisplayController",
    controllerAs:"displayController"})
```

and I add a resolve to the state so that only logged in people can access the route, such as:

```
resolve: {
    "currentUser": ["$meteor", function($meteor){
      return $meteor.requireUser();
    }]
  }
```

*taken from http://angular-meteor.com/tutorial/step_08

Doesn't this create a security hole?

Can't anyone open up the console in their browser and "re-write" the route so that it doesn't require the user?

Comment: Any restrictions you do only on client side are a security hole. As long as your server is properly restricting users from doing what they shouldn't be able to, you're safe.

Comment: Use $cookies if people logged definetely we store some user datas in cookies

Comment: We just don't render/include the secret parts on our software. It's the only way to do it. Never trust the user. Anything you send them, they can get access to. Anything they can send you, must be validated. Rules of the road.

Comment: you'll very quickly realize that worrying about this kind of "security hole" is a moot point, because, someone who's tech savvy enough to dig into and change your javascript, is also tech savvy enough to skip your javascript all together and go straight to the server for what they want.

Comment: @KevinB You are correct, and while I can protect myself with user validation on the server, I also wished to prevent people from even seeing the page through the Angular piece.  If they can see the page, then they know more about the parameters of the request and it takes some of the guess work out of the equation.

Comment: they can get that from the source anyway. It's even often neatly packaged all up into a single collection of files called "services" or "factories"

Comment: @KevinB ok, so it sounds like there is no possible way for them to see "how" to send the request then.  I'll just have to be very sure about the server side validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we target the question set forward, "Yes" would be the short answer. The truth behind that answer is though, it wasn't designed to be secure as it is impossible. The second the user/client has finished downloading the page, they technically have full access to everything you gave them. No matter how many client-side precautions you take, people could just save your files, edit them as they please and reload the page using those files. They could go to which ever route they wanted, run what ever javascript they wanted, etc.

What does this mean? Never trust the user. Ever. If you don't want someone to see something, don't include it -at all- in the response. If you hide it clientside, nothing stops the user opening up the source viewer and just digging in files to find it. Even if you minify and everything, someone out there, with enough drive, can find everything.

Same applies with API calls, socket communication, etc. The Client can send whatever they want. If they know the URL, expected data and sending method, they can just create their own fake client and send whatever they hell they want. This is why clientside validation is pretty much only useful for UI reasons (flagging boxs as red, saving time by refusing forms, etc) but you MUST revalidate and recheck -everything- server side to.

tl;dr - Yes it's "insecure" but it's not angular/ui router's fault. It's just the way it is with clientside development. If you don't want a user who doesn't have access to see something, don't include it AT ALL in the data/files you send them. Detect it and strip it out serverside.

Comment: Just to add to that - that's the reason step 8 mostly is around securing the backend with the `Parties.allow` syntax.  ui-router is just a nice addition, not for complete security